# Typo3 8.7.7 CKEditor: E-Mail link not working (a tag removed)

Tags: html, ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I'm trying to insert an e-mail address with the ckeditor. After I saved my content element (text&media), the source code showing the ckeditor looks fine

```
<a href="mailto:some@mailaddress.com" title="lalala">some@mailaddress.com</a>
```

But when I visit the webpage only the following is visible:

```
some(at)mailaddress.com
```

I found out, that the problem is the spam protection. If I enable

```
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = 1
```

The mail not rendered anymore. It's working without protection, but I want to use it.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out!
The problem was at my fluid template. I wrapped the {CONTENT} variable with

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">{CONTENT}</f:format.html>
```

It's working now after I changed this to

```
<f:format.raw>{CONTENT}</f:format.raw>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have performed the following test (TYPO3 8.7.7) and CKEditor with full configuration:

1) `config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = 1` and `config.spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst = [at]`

2) Create a CE text with image

3) write `test email` into the text editor and then use the **"link"** button to add an email address

3.1) write `test@email.it` into the text editor and then use the  **"link"** button to add an email address

3.2) write `test@email.it` into the text editor without adding the link

**Results**

3.1) the `href` attribute of the link is encrypted `(javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('...');)`

3.2) the `href` attribute of the link is encrypted `(javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('...');)` while the visible text does not become `test[at]email.it`

3.3) no link is added to the text; the visible text does not become `test[at]email.it`

Could you tell us if you installed some CKEditor plugins or some write some detail of your configuration?

Comment: I'm using a fresh installation of typo3 8.7.7 without ckeditor plugins. Inserting a hyperlink to a webpage is working fine. Tried also to add a new content element with type text with the same results.

Comment: I did not understand what steps did you exactly follow. Just writing `test@email.it` in the editor and then save? In this case the behavior I experience is the one I reported as 3.2

Comment: yeah it's really strange, tried everything. Never had this problem before. It's at least my third typo3 8 project.

Comment: What extensions do you use?

Comment: Powermail & Gridelements, but I also tried to put the content not in a grid element with the same effect.

Comment: I cant' imagine what setting changes the text test@email.it -> test(at)email.it... I am not able to make it behave like that

Comment: I upgraded typo3 from 8.7.7 to 8.7.8, but still the same problem.

Comment: Same problem on Typo3 8.7.8.

Comment: @RobertG.could you check the other answer by Ralf ?

Answer (score 0):

but if you use `<f:format.raw>`, the email address is not spam protected anymore. Thats not, what you wanted, isn't it? 
I have the problem, the `<pre>`-tag is html encoded and only works in `<f:format.raw>`, but then, the email addresses are plain.

Martin